# Qt connect "no such slot" when slot exists

Tags: qt, signals, signals-slots

I am trying to connect a signal to a slot. The project compiles fine, but at runtime I get this error:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QHeaderView::onFilterAdded(int)
```

here is my code:

```
class MySortFilterProxyModel: public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MySortFilterProxyModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MySortFilterProxyModel();
    void addFilter(int col, SteFilter *pFilter);
    void removeFilter(int col);
signals:
    void filterAdded(int);
    void filterRemoved(int);
}

class MyHeaderView: public QHeaderView
{
public:
    MyHeaderView();
    void paintSection(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, int logicalIndex) const;

public slots:
    void onFilterAdded(int);
    void onFilterRemoved(int);

private:
    QList<int> m_listFilters;
};
```

I use this line of code to connect the signal to the slot:

```
QObject::connect(&m_proxyModel, SIGNAL(filterAdded(int)), &m_headerView, SLOT(onFilterAdded(int)));
```

m_proxyModel is of type MySortFilterProxyModel and m_headerView is of type MyHeaderView. They are not pointers.

I don't get why this happens. I have connected other signals and slots using the same technique and had no problems. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I do not see how this is a duplicate of that. That addresses a general Q_OBJECT concern, whereas this question is specific to one particular problem only with Q_OBJECT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class *MyHeaderView* doesn't have Q_OBJECT macro, don't forget to *run qmake* after you add it and only after that build your project.