# QT Signal and Slot porblem:Is `No such slot` related to Protected Signal?

Tags: c++, qt4, signals-slots, qt-signals, kdevelop

I was trying to connect signal `QListWidget->itemChanged` to a custom Slot called `checkItemChanged`. I asked for right syntax in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48059796/1080355).
I'm using QT4 so I used old-string syntax as below to connect signal and slot:

```
connect(listWidget, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QListWidgetItem*)), this , SLOT(checkItemChanged(QListWidgetItem*)));
```

This connect syntax is declared in a file called `mainWindow.cpp` and its header file `mainWindow.h` is as below:

```
class mainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    mainWindow ( QWidget *parent=0, const char *name=0 );

public slots:
    void checkItemChanged(QListWidgetItem*);
```

I also defined my slot implementation in `mainWindow.cpp` as below:

```
void mainWindow::checkItemChanged(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
  if (item->checkState()==true){

    qDebug()<<"Item: "<<item->text()<<"Checked";
  }else{
    qDebug()<<"Item: "<<item->text()<<"UnChecked";
  }
}
```

So it used macro Q_OBJECT as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19886895/1080355) as common reason for `no such slot` error.

I run my project in **KDevelop IDE**, so it will automatically build `.moc` file and run `qmake` as asked in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749787/1080355)
However still I face error as below:

```
Object::connect: No such slot mainWindow::checkItemChanged(QListWidgetItem*) in /home/part/Desktop/project/P/src/gui/mainWindow.cpp:320
```

I know this is strange but I want to know may be it is related to the fact that `QListWidget->itemChanged` is protected?  Or there are some other thing that I have missed?

Comment: did you tried to rebuild whole project after runing qmake?

Comment: I did clean project and then rebuild it. The strange thing is that other connect methods in my project in the same file are working flawlessly but I have no idea why this one is not working.

Comment: Try to manually delete all files in build directory and then run qmake and rebuild. Sometimes it helps

Comment: I see no reason why this shouldn't work. As @AmirRasulov points out sometimes there are remains from previous builds (esp. moc files) that have to be cleaned up manually. If the problem persists then provide a [mcve] instead of snippets.